# How can i kill child process from the child itself?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am using `fork()` method for creating child processess to write csv files. But my child process keeps running. I have tried `process.kill()` but it terminates whole process. How do I end my child processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
const { fork } = require('child_process')

const child = fork('another_file.js')

// Do whatever you want...

child.kill(9)
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal